# Git: rollback to certain commit and push it to remote

Tags: git

I am confused with git.

```
                       I am here
                          |
=>c1=>c2=>c3=>c4=>c5=>c6=>c7 
                   |
              needed commit
```

How to get the exact code from c5 commit? I don't need c6 and c7 anymore.

Comment: any update on this? Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: @ChrisMaes did not try it yet. I will try it in two ours and I will let you know. Sorry for not giving you any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to completely remove commits c6 and c7 FOREVER?

locally:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

then to push to remote (-f to force; THIS IS DANGEROUS!)

```
git push -f
```

**NOTES:**

- git reset --hard: removes the commits AND all the changes; those commits are lost forever (at least consider them that way, they stay for a short while accessible in git reflog).
- git push -f: allows you to push to the remote; even if that means you are changing the hash of some commits; this will cause trouble if anyone else is connected to that repository!

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. It is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `git revert` also. Do the reverts one at a time.

`git revert HEAD     # Reverts c7`

`git revert HEAD~2   # Reverts c6`